# Code igniter native session namespace

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

https://github.com/appleboy/CodeIgniter-Native-Session/blob/master/libraries/Session.php

If you run multiple applications on the same site, please modify your_application/config/session.php file line:

```
// Session namespace
$config['sess_namespace'] = 'your_application_name';
```

In my setup I run the same application across different sub domains. Does this apply to me? Or is this for multiple applications running on same domain?

Comment: That means: If you have multiple application something like `/application1/`, `/application2/`, `/application3/`, each application use own session configuration.

Comment: Ah ok I don't think that applies to me because I have subdomain sand each subdomain gets a unique session id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you have in [`$config['cookie_domain']`](https://github.com/appleboy/CodeIgniter-Native-Session/blob/master/libraries/Session.php#L63).

By default (if you don't specify), php will set the domain to the domain of the current request meaning that the session cookie created for *domain.com* will be sent to the ***www***.domain.com and every other higher level subdomains too (see the [$domain](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) parameter).

If you are using the "main" domain (one segment + tld, ie.: domain.com) you might need to redirect the traffic to a subdomain (like www) before you set any cookies, or you can of course use the `sess_namespace` setting.